# Nginx Rewrite domain to Subfolder excluding trailing slash

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to rewrite a domain to include a language path but without the trailing slash.

So

www.example.com => www.example.com/en

www.example.com/page/ => www.example.com/en/page

www.example.com/page => www.example.com/en/page

I am currently using this config, but it is not working as expected.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com/public;
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  index index.php index.html;

  location = / {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/en$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Mainly,

www.example.com => www.example.com/en/ => www.example.com/en

www.example.com/page => www.example.com/page

This code is also playing havoc on some of the http_post requests.

Comment: `rewrite ^/(?!en/) /en$request_uri redirect;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a POST, the redirect is downgraded to a GET (this is normal behaviour). The 307 response can be used to repeat a POST with the new URI. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for more.

In which case, you will need to rewrite your configuration to use `return 307` statements. You can use regular expression location blocks to capture the URI without its trailing `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

One way to identify URIs that do not begin with `/en`, is to use a `location ^~ /en` block to process all URIs that *do* begin with `/en`, and use the regular expression location block to capture everything else.

For example:

```
location = / {
    return 307 /en;
}
location ~ ^(/.*?)/?$ {
    return 307 /en$1;
}
location ^~ /en {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer, however there is something about the second location rule that seems to add multiple /en to the end of the URL, like it is caught in a loop

Comment: The last location is supposed to capture any URI that begins with `/en`.